# How to multiply two pandas columns from seperate dataframes together?

Tags: pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, one as a look up table and one 'main' table.

The look up table is so.

```
import pandas as pd
lu_dict = {'state': ['OH', 'TX', 'IA', 'WY', 'KS'], 'fire_pct':[0.542630,.174425,0.206752,0.004621,0.441946]
          , 'hail_pct':[0.008787,0.440272,0.422005,0.434709,0.312338]
          ,'tw_pct':[0.101449,0.179536,0.159886,0.028349,0.151416]
          ,'other_pct':[0.224980,0.160096,0.149560,0.393357,0.036523]
          ,'wp_pct':[0.122154,0.045671,0.061796,0.138963,0.057777]}
lu = pd.DataFrame(lu_dict)
```

The main table is like so:

```
preds_dict = {'state':['OH', 'TX', 'IA', 'WY', 'KS'],
             'fire_preds':[.01,.02,.03,.015,.66]
          , 'hail_preds':[.03,.005,.12,.23,.006]
          ,'tw_preds':[.001,.02,.0035,.04,.02]
          ,'other_preds':[.003,.05,.001,.01,.06]
          ,'wp_preds':[.002,.03,.005,.01,.04]}

preds = pd.DataFrame(preds_dict)
```

I need the observation in the 'main' table to match on the `state` column in the look up table, then multiply `fire_pct` in the look up table by 'fire_preds` in the 'main' table, 'other_pct' by 'other_preds', 'wp_pct' by 'wp_preds' etc.

If a dictionary would work better for a lookup table, that's fine.  I just need to keep the main table in it's current data frame form for further processing.

Finally, the output I'm looking for is the sum of those multiplication outputs in one column.

Comment: look into `pandas.merge`

Comment: What is your expected output from this data?

Comment: @ScottBoston. My bad on not putting that.  Edited to include now.  I would like the sum of those multiplication products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to do some renaming to get pandas to align data correctly.

```
mults = (lu.rename(columns=dict(zip(lu.columns, preds.columns))).set_index('state') * 
         preds.set_index('state'))
print(mults)
```

Output:

```
       fire_preds  hail_preds  tw_preds  other_preds  wp_preds
state                                                         
OH       0.005426    0.000264  0.000101     0.000675  0.000244
TX       0.003488    0.002201  0.003591     0.008005  0.001370
IA       0.006203    0.050641  0.000560     0.000150  0.000309
WY       0.000069    0.099983  0.001134     0.003934  0.001390
KS       0.291684    0.001874  0.003028     0.002191  0.002311
```

Sum products:

```
mults.sum()

fire_preds     0.306871
hail_preds     0.154963
tw_preds       0.008414
other_preds    0.014954
wp_preds       0.005624
dtype: float64
```

Sum by states:

```
mults.sum(axis=1)

state
OH    0.006711
TX    0.018656
IA    0.057861
WY    0.106510
KS    0.301089
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. I have multiple columns in my actual main table (62K-ish), multiple observations per state.  Will this still work?

Comment: Yep.   This is using vectorize operations so it does it all in one pass.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm gettin all null values and the first few hundred of the index seems to be predictions before the states start.

Comment: On key thing about pandas It aligns all data on the indexes.  Both row and columns... so you your dataframes will yeild NaN if they are mis aligned.  IE.  One dataframe has indexes with 1-10 and the other dataframe has indexes 11-20.  Also, this the same with column headers.

Comment: Make sure your index match in your dataframes and column headers.  And dtype matters.

Comment: i think it may be the column headers.  In the preds, I have the ones as above plus three extra value columns I'll need later.

Comment: Ok. I got this to work but is there anyway it can keep the same order.  This is sorting by state and I need to keep the same order to join back up to the original data set.

Comment: If you join it joins on indexes.... so sorting doesn't matter when joining, but you call always add either sort_values by columnname or sort_index by levels.